# Option Strict Set to ON issue of late binding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
' 1St step
Dim irregularWeldSpots = From row In spotsTable.AsEnumerable()
                     Where (CStr(row("FUNCJOINTCODE")) = currentJointKey
        And ((Convert.ToDecimal(row("RESULTUNIT")) / Convert.ToDecimal(row("LENSDIAMUNIT"))) >= defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent
        And (Convert.ToDecimal(row("RESULTUNIT")) / Convert.ToDecimal(row("LENSDIAMUNIT"))) < insufficientSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent)
        Or (Convert.ToDecimal(row("RESULTUNIT")) / Convert.ToDecimal(row("LENSDIAMUNIT")) < defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent))
        Select Case row
        , IsInsufficient = ((Convert.ToDecimal(row("RESULTUNIT")) / Convert.ToDecimal(row("LENSDIAMUNIT"))) >= defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent
        And (Convert.ToDecimal(row("RESULTUNIT")) / Convert.ToDecimal(row("LENSDIAMUNIT"))) < insufficientSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent)
        , IsDefect = (Convert.ToDecimal(row("RESULTUNIT")) / Convert.ToDecimal(row("LENSDIAMUNIT"))) < defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent

' 2nd step      
EvaluateDistanceBetweenIrregularSpots(resultTable,definitionsTable,currentJointKey,allWeldSpots,allWeldSpotsCount,defectiveWeldSpotsCount,
                                    insufficientWeldspotsCount,irregularWeldSpots)

' 3rd step                                      
Private Sub EvaluateDistanceBetweenIrregularSpots(ByRef resultTable As DataTable, ByRef definitionsTable As DataTable, As String, allWeldSpots As IEnumerable, allWeldSpotsCount As Integer, As Integer, insufficientWeldspotsCount As Integer,
                                                As IEnumerable)
    If Not ((insufficientWeldspotsCount + defectiveWeldSpotsCount) > 1) Then Return
    For Each spot1 In irregularWeldSpots
        If spot1.row("XUNIT") Is Nothing Then Continue For

        For Each spot2 In irregularWeldSpots
            If spot1.row("SPOTDESC") = spot2.row("SPOTDESC") Then Continue For

            Dim x0 As Double = spot1.row("XUNIT")
            Dim x As Double = spot2.row("XUNIT")
            Dim y0 As Double = spot1.row("YUNIT")
            Dim y As Double = spot2.row("YUNIT")
            Dim z0 As Double = spot1.row("ZUNIT")
            Dim z As Double = spot2.row("ZUNIT")
            Dim distance As Double = Math.Sqrt((x - x0) ^ 2 + (y - y0) ^ 2 + (z - z0) ^ 2)

            If distance >= spot1.row("LENSDIAMUNIT") Then Continue For

            Dim message As String = String.Empty
            If spot1.IsDefect And spot2.IsDefect Then
                message = "One defect spot was found inside the sphere around another defect spot"
            ElseIf (spot1.IsDefect And spot2.IsInsufficient) Or (spot1.IsInsufficient And spot2.IsDefect) Then
                message = "One insufficient spot was found inside the sphere around a defect spot"
            End If

            If message.Length > 0 Then
                Dim newRow As DataRow = resultTable.NewRow()
                newRow("JointNo") = jointNumber
                newRow("StatusMessage") = message
                newRow("SpotCount") = allWeldSpotsCount
                newRow("Insufficient") = insufficientWeldspotsCount
                newRow("Defective") = defectiveWeldSpotsCount
                newRow("SphereRadius") = "-"
                resultTable.Rows.Add(newRow)
            End If

        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Issue on 3rd step of late binding after option strict is set to ON on "spot1.row(..) & spot2.row(..)"

Comment: Use `CStr(spot1.row("SPOTDESC"))`, or whatever type conversion is correct for the item.

Comment: In future, please post code form separate methods separately, so that it is obvious that they don't follow on from each other. You basically can't pass anonymous typed objects between methods and use early binding.  Anonymous types are only known in the context that they are created.  If you want to pass objects between methods then you must either use late binding, Reflection or named types.  The latter is the generally-preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work out what to do there from your earlier code. In step 1 you appear to have recognised the fact that indexing `row` returns what is probably an `Object` reference so, if you want to use a value as its actual type then you need to cast/convert to that type.  In the code for step 1 you have:

```
CStr(row("FUNCJOINTCODE"))
```

and:

```
(Convert.ToDecimal(row("RESULTUNIT"))
```

where you want to use a value as type `String` or type `Decimal` so why should it be any different in step 3 where you want to use a value as type `Double`, e.g.

```
Dim x0 As Double = CDbl(spot1.row("XUNIT"))
```

While it's not a big deal, you really ought to only be using `Convert` when you actually need to convert the type of the data.  For instance, if `row("RESULTUNIT")` actually contains a `String` and you need to convert it to a `Decimal` then `Convert.ToDecimal` is appropriate but if the data is already a `Decimal` then you are only performing a cast because there's no conversion required.  In that case, you ought to use `CDec`.

Also, you shouldn't be using the same complex expression over and over again.  In step 1, you use `(Convert.ToDecimal(row("RESULTUNIT"))` many, many times, which is bad.  I would be writing that step 1 code like this:

```
Dim irregularWeldSpots = From row In spotsTable.AsEnumerable()
                         Let resultUnit = CDec(row("RESULTUNIT")),
                             lensDiamUnit = CDec(row("LENSDIAMUNIT"))
                         Where (CStr(row("FUNCJOINTCODE")) = currentJointKey AndAlso
                                resultUnit / lensDiamUnit >= defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent AndAlso
                                resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < insufficientSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent) OrElse
                               resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent
                         Select row,
                                IsInsufficient = resultUnit / lensDiamUnit >= defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent AndAlso
                                                 resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < insufficientSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent,
                                IsDefect = resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent
```

Note that that is now far easier to read with better indenting, the use of a `Let` clause to create variables local to the query and it also uses the more correct `AndAlso` and `OrElse` rather than 'And`and`Or`.  I've also removed redundant parentheses but you may prefer to retain those.

On the subject of parentheses, I wonder whether you have them correct in that `Where` clause.  Note that `And` and `AndAlso` operators are always evaluated in preference to `Or` and `OrElse` operators so, with or without the redundant parentheses you had, you are matching records where either the first three conditions match or the last condition matches.  Perhaps that is what you want but I suspect that what you actually want is for the first condition to match as well as either the second and third or the fourth.  If so then this:

```
Where (CStr(row("FUNCJOINTCODE")) = currentJointKey AndAlso
       resultUnit / lensDiamUnit >= defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent AndAlso
       resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < insufficientSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent) OrElse
      resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent
```

would be come this:

```
Where CStr(row("FUNCJOINTCODE")) = currentJointKey AndAlso
      ((resultUnit / lensDiamUnit >= defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent AndAlso
        resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < insufficientSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent) OrElse
       resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent)
```

EDIT:

The issue is more clear now that I realise that that code is from more than one method.  Instead of using an anonymous type, you should define your own type:

```
Public Class SpotRow
    Public Property Row As DataRow
    Public Property IsInsufficient As Boolean
    Public Property IsDefect As Boolean
End Class
```

You can then change the LINQ query to create instances of that type instead of an anonymous type:

```
Select New SpotRow With {.Row = row,
                         .IsInsufficient = resultUnit / lensDiamUnit >= defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent AndAlso
                                           resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < insufficientSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent,
                         .IsDefect = resultUnit / lensDiamUnit < defectiveSpotIfSizeLessThanPercent}
```

You can then pass the generated list as an `IEnumerable(Of SpotRow)` instead of an `IEnumerable`.  I'm not going to try to provide the method declaration because the code you posted is nonsensical because it has parameter types with no parameter names.  Just change the type of the relevant parameter.  You'll find that you can now access the `Row` property of each item.

Comment: Thanks but issue is compile time and on spot1.row(..)
And spot1.IsInsuffiecient..
As "Option strict On disallows late binding."

Comment: OK, so yet again someone has caused confusion by poorly formatting their code.  I now see that that code is actually in different methods and the relevant parameter is declared as just `IEnumerable`.  That means that each item will be retrieved as an `Object` reference and you need to cast it as its actual type. That's a problem though, because you're using an anonymous type.  You simply can't do that.  You need to define your own type with those properties and create instances of that instead.  I'll add a code example.